# How to get a list of all disks ordered on softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-storage

I am trying to prepare a report with all the storage ordered on soft layer for an account. Is there an API to retrieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

To list all the storage on SoftLayer for an account you can use the following rest call example:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[id,username,capacityGb,guestId,hardwareId,hostId,nasType,storageType]
```

This request will show you all the network storage such as: Block Storage(Endurance, Performance), File Storage(Endurance, Performance), Object Storage, Evault Backup.

Note: Take into account the Evault Backup items are other kind of storages which are attached to virtual servers, they are able to ensure that your data is safely stored outside of your device and protected if it gets lost([IBM Cloud Backup](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/infrastructure/Backup/index.html#getting-started-with-ibm-cloud-backup-services)).

If you want to retrieve the network storages separately e.g. Block Storage, File Storage, you can run the below rest call examples using object filter:

**Block Storage ("nasType": "ISCSI")**

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[id,username,capacityGb,guestId,hardwareId,hostId,nasType,storageType]&objectFilter={"networkStorage": {"nasType": {"operation": "ISCSI"}}}
```

**File Storage("nasType": "NAS")**

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[id,username,capacityGb,guestId,hardwareId,hostId,nasType,storageType]&objectFilter={"networkStorage": {"nasType": {"operation": "NAS"}}}
```

**Object Storage("nasType": "HUB")**

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[id,username,capacityGb,guestId,hardwareId,hostId,nasType,storageType]&objectFilter={"networkStorage": {"nasType": {"operation": "HUB"}}}
```

Reference:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage/

Or you can use the following specific methods for each storage option:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getHubNetworkStorage/
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getIscsiNetworkStorage/
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNasNetworkStorage/